# Как называют людей, которые просят денег на проживание или еду?

Tags: лексика

Как называют людей, которые просят денег на проживание или еду?

Comment: Самое типичное: "Попрошайки"

Answer (score 1):

Нейтрально: "(уличный) **нищий** (**нищенка** в случае женщины)", пренебрежительно - "**попрошайка**", "**побирушка**".

Comment: И ещё - побирушка

Comment: Да, спасибо, пытался вспомнить ещё одно слово и не вспомнил, - добавлю, если вы не против :).